# Laravel 5.4 Accessors doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a User Eloquent model with attribute phone_1

here are method, but it does not work:

```
public function getPhone1Attribute($value)
    {
        xdebug_break();
        if ($value !== null) {
            return $this->formatPhone($value);
        }
        return $value;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it does not work'?  Do you get an error?

Comment: @kerrin No. I don't have any error. Method does not called.

Comment: Can you share the code that you expect would call this method?

Comment: Do you try to access it like `$model->phone_1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutator not working for if starting letter integer.Since mutator take first letter as capital so you cant assign 1 since we cant make interger to capital

suppose if you change `phone_1` to `phone_one` then it will work

```
public function getPhoneOneAttribute($value){
}
```

if you change `phone_1` to `phone_o1ne` then it will work.since here p and o are letters for that

```
public function getPhoneO1neAttribute($value){
    }
```

Comment: Yes. I think about it, but hoped that there is a solution without renaming attr. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrii.as per my knowlege i think no option but i cant say that 100% i am right